# I have to pass the multiple <int:pk> in a single endpoint for django rest api?

Tags: django, api, url, serialization, primary-key

[image]

Here in the above picture, I have all the packages shown for single destination id ie pk=1. Now, what i want to show is single package of single destination ie my endpoint should be localhost/api/destination/1/package/1 or something like this. My views and serializers are as shown below:

```
class Destination(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    dest_image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='dest_image',
                                      processors=[ResizeToFill(100, 50)],
                                      format='JPEG',
                                      options={'quality': 60})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def packages(self):
        return self.package_set.all()


class Package(models.Model):
    destination = models.ForeignKey(Destination, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    package_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    duration = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    discount = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="15% OFF")
    discounted_price = models.IntegerField(default=230)
    savings = models.IntegerField(default=230)
    rating = models.IntegerField(choices=((1, 1),
                                          (2, 2),
                                          (3, 3),
                                          (4, 4),
                                          (5, 5))
                                 )
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='image',
                                      processors=[ResizeToFill(100, 50)],
                                      format='JPEG',
                                      options={'quality': 60})
    date_created = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.package_name

class DestinationPackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Package
        # fields = ['id', 'destination']
        fields = '__all__'
        



class DestinationwithPackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    packages = DestinationPackageSerializer(many= True,read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Destination
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'dest_image', 'packages']
        # fields = '__all__'
        # depth = 1





class DestinationFrontSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Destination
        # fields = ['id', 'package']
        fields = '__all__'
        # depth = 1
```

My views are:

```
class DestinationFrontListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Destination.objects.all().order_by('?')[:4]
    # queryset = Package.objects.all().order_by('-date_created')[:4]
    serializer_class = DestinationFrontSerializer

class DestinationPackageListAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Destination.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DestinationwithPackageSerializer
```

My urls are:

```
path('api/destinations', views.DestinationFrontListAPIView.as_view(), name='api-destinations'),
        path('api/destinations/<int:pk>', views.DestinationPackageListAPIView.as_view(), name='api-destinations-packages'),
```

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think that you need `destination_id` in the URL for package?
I believe it is not needed. Only `package_id` should be enough - it is primary key and it uniquely identifies the package.

If you do want to include `destination_id` to the URL and take it into account when fetching package, you can do it like this:

```
# urls.py
path(
    'api/destinations/<int:destination_id>/package/<int:pk>',
    views.DestinationPackageItemIView.as_view(),
    name='api-destinations-package',
),


# views.py
class DestinationPackageItemIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = DestinationPackageSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        destination_id = self.kwargs['destination_id']
        return Package.objects.filter(destination_id=destination_id)
```

Comment: Its because, I have 3 pages on the frontend. In the homepage, I have destinations. When I click one of the destianation(for eg: DUbai), it will show all (around 10) packages( like dubai island package, dubai city tour package) on the 2nd page. Now, there is a third page which have to show the detail of a single package, when I click one of the package on the second page. I hope it explains.

Comment: I understand that 2nd page has destination_id in the URL. But it does not mean that the third page must have it too. It would work just fine if you include only package_id (taken from the 2nd page) - 'api/packages/<int:pk>'

Comment: Its because the second page contains packages from only one destination.If we click Dubai in first page, it will only show packages from dubai destinations not all packages. But if I make api/package/<int:pk>, then it might be packages from any destination for eg dubai europe, thailand etc.I am sorry, but this is what i have understood.

Comment: It is just like in a office, there are several staffs in different departments & I want to view the details of a single employee from a unique department.

Comment: @sarojpaudel - alright, I've updated the answer with code sample of how that can be done. Please note though that destination_id in the URL is not really necessary.